# Validate number of checkboxes selected dependent on radio button choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am looking to JavaScript validate a form's checkboxes but I cannot get my code to throw the error message.

If the `3daypass` radio button is chosen, 3 checkboxes in a certain section `#matthewpeckham` should be selected, etc. This is the code I have run onSubmit() :

```
function chooseDaysCorrect() {

var totalDaysChecked = 0;
var totalDaysChecked = $('#matthewpeckham').find("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;

if (document.getElementById('3daypass').checked && totalDaysChecked != 3) {
    alert("Please select enough days for your chosen delegate pass from the CONFERENCE PASS section above");
    return false;
}
else if (document.getElementById('2daypass').checked && totalDaysChecked != 2) {
    alert("Please select enough days for your chosen delegate pass from the CONFERENCE PASS section above");
    return false;
}
else if (document.getElementById('1daypass').checked && totalDaysChecked != 1) {
    alert("Please select enough days for your chosen delegate pass from the CONFERENCE PASS section above");
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}


}
```

Is `("[type='checkbox']:checked").length` the correct method to count the number of checkboxes that have been chosen? Where have I gone wrong?

I have also tried the following way of running the function on form Submit, but this doesn't work either:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#classic').submit(function() {

    var totalDaysChecked = 0;
    var totalDaysChecked = $('#matthewpeckham').find("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;

    if (document.getElementById('3daypass').checked && totalDaysChecked != 3) {
        alert("Please select enough days for your chosen delegate pass from the CONFERENCE PASS section above");
        return false;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('2daypass').checked && totalDaysChecked != 2) {
        alert("Please select enough days for your chosen delegate pass from the CONFERENCE PASS section above");
        return false;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('1daypass').checked && totalDaysChecked != 1) {
        alert("Please select enough days for your chosen delegate pass from the CONFERENCE PASS section above");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

});

});
```

Comment: This way should work correctly. Did you try without the `#matthewpeckham` selector? Without the `:checked`?

Comment: Also, HTML 4 does not permit id attributes to begin with a number, so `3daypass`, `2daypass` may be suspect. Did you try changing those?

Comment: I have tried all these suggestions, but it still doesn't show the error. Other validation on the radio buttons works so it can't be the ID name. I have also tried `onSubmit="chooseDaysCorrect();"` and `onSubmit="return chooseDaysCorrect();"` in case it was that, but nothing either.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following code, first create your forms as usual, and to each checkbox add a custom data-* field with the required value to look for:

HTML:

```
<form class="classic" id="classic">
  <input type="checkbox" id="3daypass" data-expected="3" ></input>
  <input type="checkbox" id="2daypass" data-expected="2" ></input>
  <input type="checkbox" id="1daypass" data-expected="1" ></input>
  <input type="submit" value="click"></input>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
```

$("form#classic").submit(function() {

```
 totalDaysChecked = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length
  $("[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(index, value) {
        if($(value).attr('data-expected') != totalDaysChecked) {
          alert("Please select enough days for your chosen delegate pass from the CONFERENCE PASS section above");
        } else { 
          return true
        }
  });
return false;
```

}) 
})

Try it here: http://jsbin.com/ipazow/1/